# After installing MRTK and OpenXR plugin to Unity project I get compiler errors: The type or namespace name could not be found

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator, openxr

So I have been trying to follow the tutorial found at: https://medium.com/@perudayani/connecting-hololens-part-3-of-3-f010481f288b , I got through part 1-2 no problem. But in part 3 they referenced an old MRTK package, so I try to install the new MRTK using the MRFeatureTool and the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/new-openxr-project-with-mrtk. I chose only the features: "Mixed Reality toolkit Foundation", "Mixed Reality Tollkit Tools", and "Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin". After I set it up and followed the microsoft docs guide, my project has the following compiler errors as seen from the picture link "compiler errors on unity photo". Before I installed MRTK and the OpenXR plugin to my Unity project I didn't have any compiler errors. My version of unity is 2020.2.3f1 I can't seem to find a solution, I would really appreciate some help. I want to fix these compiler errors, and I'm building this project to use for a senior design project. Thank you.
[compiler errors on unity photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACf5q.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with MRTK and Open XR, and it has been fixed in later Unity versions, please refer to [Known issues in Unity versions and packages - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/known-issues), and try with **Unity 2020.3.35f1**.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you! I would 1 up but I can't vote yet :p